# how to Split expense based on multiple expense divided amount multiple user with different share?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, expense-splitting

I want to split expenses based on:

```
1. Expense By user.
2. Divided by users.
3. Share of each user.
```

I want output with list of users who owes money to other users.
I have tried calculating in different ways but nothing was helpful.

**Would really appreciate if someone can help...**

Input Json:

```js
var expenseObj = [
  {
    expenseBy:{
      user:"A",
      amount:1000
    },
    dividedBy: [
      {
        user:"A",
        amount:100
      },{
        user:"B",
        amount:500
      },{
        user:"C",
        amount:400
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    expenseBy:{
      user:"B",
      amount:2000
    },
    dividedBy: [
      {
        user:"A",
        amount:1000
      },{
        user:"B",
        amount:400
      },{
        user:"C",
        amount:600
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Please make the question clear, what is the input and what is the expected output.

Comment: @SomeDude - Basically input is the attached JSON with array of multiple expenses. Each expense have detail of who has paid it and how it will be divided. 
Expected output can be a json with list of users who need to pay money and to whom: eg: {payBy: "A", payTo:"B", amount: 200}

Comment: what is the output format expected ? Which user owes to which user ? Lets say A, B owe to C ? Is  { A : C, B: C } output?

Comment: from your input, it seems that the output is just list of users who is other than one mentioned in expenseBy. Can expenseBy have more than one user?

Answer (score 0):

```
  for (let i = 0; i<expenseObj.length; i++){
      var share = expenseObj[i].expenseBy.amount/expenseObj[i].dividedBy.length;
      var addedBy = expenseObj[i].expenseBy.user;
      var addedAmount = expenseObj[i].expenseBy.amount;
      for(j=0; j<expenseObj[i].dividedBy.length;j++){
        var amount = share-expenseObj[i].dividedBy[j].amount
          if( amount >= 0){
            console.log(expenseObj[i].dividedBy[j].user+" owes "+amount+" in expense added by "+addedBy+" of amount "+addedAmount);
          }
      }
  }
```

I hope it would give you some basic idea about what you want to do.

Comment: you added user C where?

Comment: in the above expenseObj object.